# Как отобразить выбранные checkbox в Django при использовании ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, multiple

Помогите)
Как отобразить выбранные checkbox в Django при использовании ModelMultipleChoiceField на странице редактирования ресурса.
Отмечаю нужные чекбоксы, сохраняю. Всё сохраняется. Но отмеченные чекбоксы не "горят". Когда снова заходишь в редактор не видно, что было отмечено.

```
##Моя модель:

class Dish(models.Model):
    titl = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
    ingr = models.TextField(verbose_name="Ingredients", null=True, blank=True)
    auth = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name = 'auth', verbose_name="Author")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titl

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dish'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dish'
        ordering = ['-time_crea', 'titl']
```

```
##Моя форма:

class DishForm(ModelForm):

    titl = forms.CharField(label='Title', widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'inp',       'placeholder': 'Title'}),         required=True)
    ingr = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label='Ingredients',
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
        queryset=Ingredients.objects.all(),
        required=False, 
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Dish
        fields = ['titl', 'ingr']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DishForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ingr'].initial = self.instance.ingr
```

```
## Моя вьюха:

class ChanDish(UpdateView):
    model = Dish
    form_class = DishForm
    template_name = 'app_dish/chandish.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'dish_id'
    context_object_name = 'data'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('lgn')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listdish')

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Editor of' + ' ' + str(context['data'].titl)
        return context
```

```
## Мой шаблон (кусочек с формой)

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="error">{{ error }}</div>

    <div class="groups">
        <label>Title:</label> 
        {{ form.titl }}
    </div>

    <div class="groups">
        <label>Ingredients:</label>
        {{ form.ingr }}
    </div>

    <div class="span12 left buts">
        <div class="span3"><button type="submit" class="btn">Сохранить</button></div>
        <div class="span3 left"><a href="{% url 'itemdish' data.id %}">Вернуться не сохраняя</a></div>
        <div class="span3 left"><a href="{% url 'remodish' data.id %}"  class="rem">Удалить</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ сам.
В моделях, всего лишь, для моего поля ingr надо было указать ManyToManyField.

```
ingr = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredients', verbose_name="Ingredients", null=True, blank=True)
```

С формой, вьюхой и шаблоном вроде всё норм.